# How to compute $\sup_{f\in\mathcal F}|f(0)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> Consider $\mathcal F = \{f$ holomorphic in $\Bbb D$ with $f(\Bbb D)\subset\Bbb D,$ $f\left(\frac12\right)=f'\left(\frac12\right)=0\}$, where $\Bbb D$ is the unit disc. Compute $\sup_{f\in\mathcal F}|f(0)|$.

I was asked this on a exam, and I could only think about how every $f\in\mathcal F$ verifies that $|f(z)|<1$, for every $z\in B(0,1)$. So I said that $\sup_{f\in\mathcal F}|f(0)|=1$.

It felt too easy, so I don't think it is correct? In case it wasn't, what was I supossed to do?

Comment: Well, it is surely true that $\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} |f(0)| \leq 1$, but this just uses the invariance.

Comment: So how can I be more precise? How could I use the other condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $T(z) = \frac{1/2-z}{1-z/2}$ be the Möbius transformation which maps the unit disk onto itself with $T(0)=1/2$ and $T(1/2) = 0$, and define $g=f \circ T$.

- Show that $g: \Bbb D \to \Bbb D$ satisfies $g(0) = g'(0) = 0$.
- Conclude that $|g(z)| \le |z|^2$ for all $z \in \Bbb D$. (*Hint:* This is related to the Schwarz lemma.)
- Conclude that $|f(0)| \le 1/4$.
- Consider the function $T(z)^2$ to show that $1/4$ is not only an upper bound, but the supremum.

Comment: Didn't expect to use here Möbius transformations. Thank you for answering!

Comment: Nice answer and even nicer clues. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Blaschke factor $T(z)=(z+1/2)/(1+z/2)$. Let $f \in {\cal F}$
and set $g(z):=f(T(z))$. Then $g(\mathbb{D}) \subseteq \mathbb{D}$, $g(0)=f(1/2)=0$ and $g'(0)=f'(1/2)\cdot T'(0)=0$. Thus $g(z)=z^2h(z)$ for some
$h \in H(\mathbb{D})$. By the maximum modulus principle $|h(z)| \le 1$
on $\mathbb{D}$. Thus $|f(0)|=|g(-1/2)| \le 1/4$. Setting
$f_{max}(z)=(T^{-1}(z))^2$ we have  $f_{max} \in {\cal F}$ and $|f_{max}(0)|=1/4$.
Thus $\sup_{f \in \cal F} |f(0)|=1/4$ and the supremum is a maximum.

Comment: I see now. Thank you so much for answering!